# How to scroll android screen by AndroidViewClient

Tags: python-3.x, androidviewclient

Currently, I'm working on Snapchat and I want to scroll the screen slightly

```
1.device.vc.dump()
2.device.vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.snapchat.android:id/neon_header_avatar_container").touch()
3.device.vc.dump()
```

Now I want to scroll the screen to findViewWithText `My friends.` so how I can do it,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `culebra` and generate the python code needed for scrolling or dragging.

Run

```
culebra -Gu --scale=0.25
```

then right-click and open the command dialog, select **Drag dialog** and grab the points clicking on the device image (using Settings here as an example)

[image]

something like the following code will be generated

```
device.dragDip((184.73, 699.64), (176.0, 443.64), 1000, 20, 0)
vc.sleep(1)
vc.dump(window=-1)
```

When executed you will see the device scrolling.

Comment: device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.drag((184.73, 699.64), (176.0, 443.64), 1000, 20, 0)
It's working now, with this.
Thank you so much Milano.

Comment: why we use it sir...  vc.dump(window=-1)

Comment: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/viewclient.py#L3399 it's the default argument, so no need to specify it